# Custom validator not called on empty input value referring a two level nested property

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, custom-validators

I have an input text which does not call custom validator when it has two level of nested entities in value.

```
<p:inputText id="valueField" value="#{bean.obj1.obj2.value}" maxlength="50">
  <f:validator validatorId="requiredValidator" />
  <p:ajax event="blur" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message id="idMsg" for="valueField"/>
```

It works perfectly when I give some value, but whenever I try with an empty value, it does not invoke validator.

And if change the value to `#{bean.value}` then also it works.

Comment: Hi,
did you create a custom validator "requiredValidator"? 
You are using a custom validator with a name "requiredValidator", please add the custom validator code

Comment: by the way, you do not have to add a custom validator for "required" validation because its already provided by JSF, you can use it as:
<p:inputText id="valueField" value="#{bean.obj1.obj2.value}" maxlength="50" required="true" requiredMessage="some message">

Comment: Hi @AliSaleh , I do have custom validator. Here based on some business requirement i have to show two or more messages for required validation. Like for no value "Required" for spaces "Only spaces are not allowed". Something like that.

Comment: 1. my validator works perfectly if some values are passed like special characters. 2. And for other fields where i am not using objects even for null value it shows required message. But in this case it is not.

Comment: Its hard to think of possible causes without looking into the bean code and validator code, could you please add them, but in general the problem that is the object is null (obj1 or obj2) which means that validator can not reach the value to check it.

Comment: @AliSaleh my bean code is something like when i load my page i call a method which contains this snippet `obj1 = new obj1(); Obj2 obj2 = new obj2(); obj1.setObj2(obj2);`

Answer (score 1):

JSF does not bother with blank fields by default; you need to specify that behaviour by configuration. Assuming that there's no bug in your validator, add the following config param to your *web.xml*

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Otherwise, you should just set `required="true"` on the input or the `<f:validateRequired/>` tag on the input component, and save yourself all that typing

Comment: Can you explain *"And if change the value to #{bean.value} then also it works."*?

Comment: Not from the information posted, no @BalusC. Can you?